# How to access accessor's instance variable from a subclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor

How to access `attr_accessor`'s instance variable from a subclass?

```
class A
  attr_accessor :somevar
  @somevar = 123
  puts @somevar
end

class B < A
  def meth
    puts @somevar
  end
end

B.new.meth
```

puts `nil`...

P.S. I can use ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the instance variable in an initialize method -- this gets called whenever a new class instance is created:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :somevar
  def initialize
    @somevar = 123
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not have a instance of A to assign a value. Put an initialize method on A so while creating an instance of B, you can pass somevar value as a parameter to the new function:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :somevar

  def initialize(somevar)
    @somevar = somevar
  end
end

class B < A
  def meth
    puts @somevar
  end
end

B.new('LOL').meth
```